# asp.net ajax property value timestamp is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem with the value assignment and retrieval in asp.net ajax. The value of timestamp is undefined

Code:

```
 /// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>

 Type.registerNamespace("LabelTimeExtender1");

 LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1 = function(element) {
 LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1.initializeBase(this, [element]);
 this._testelement=this.get_element();
 this._timestamp= this.get_element().attributes['TimeStamp'].value;
 alert(_timestamp);

},

 LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1.prototype = {
initialize: function() {
    LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
    setInterval (this.timer,1000);
    alert("after");

},
dispose: function() {        
    //Add custom dispose actions here
    LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
},
timer: function(){

   alert(this.timestamp);
            var splitdate=this._timestamp.split(/[:]+/);
            alert(splitdate);
            var date= new Date(this._timestamp);
            alert( date.toString());
            var datenow= new Date ();
            alert(datenow.toString());
            this._element.innerText=" ";
            alert(this._element);
              if(date.getUTCFullYear<datenow.getUTCFullYear)
            {
            alert("year");
             var myelement= this.get_element();
             myelement .innerHTML= date.getUTCFullYear.toString();
            }
            if(date.getUTCMonth<datenow.getUTCMonth)
            {
            alert("month");
            this.get_element().innerHTML=date.getUTCMonth.toString();
            }
            if(date.getUTCDay<datenow.getUTCDay)
            {
            this.get_element().innerHTML=date.getUTCDay.toString();
            }
            if(date.getUTCHours <datenow.getUTCHours )
            {
             this.get_element().innerHTML=date.getUTCHours .toString();
            }
            if(date.getUTCMinutes<datenow.getUTCMinutes)
            {
            this.get_element().innerHTML=date.getUTCMinutes.toString();
            }


},
   set_timestamp: function(value)
  {
  this._timestamp=value;
  },

    get_timestamp: function()
   {
   return this._timestamp;
   }



}
 LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1.registerClass('LabelTimeExtender1.ClientBehavior1',  Sys.UI.Behavior);

if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

Why is the value of `_timestamp` undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest moving the code which sets `this._timestamp` into your `initialize` function.

My other suggestion is to use the getters and setters even within your own code to ensure encapsulation. So, the alerts would actually be `alert(this.get_timestamp())`. And, in your `initialize` function, you would call `this.set_timestamp(this.get_element().attributes['TimeStamp'].value)`.

Thanks to the comment I see the problem is actually in the setInterval call. When you call `window.setInterval(this.timer, 1000);`, when the `timer` function is called `this` refers to `window`, not to your object. So instead, do something like this:

```
var self = this;
window.setInterval(function () { 
    self.timer(); 
}, 1000);
```

That will make `this` inside of `timer()` refer to the correct object.

Comment: the problem is that when i try to access the this._timestamp in timer function the value is either undefined or does not work at all. still no hope alert(this.get_timestamp()); this line now does not run at all.

Comment: I am really exhausted. please do something.

Comment: You could try setting this up in http://jsFiddle.net, but it might be difficult. You may want to run your code through http://jslint.com/ to ensure there are no syntax errors. For instance, there is a comma after the first end bracket, but there should be a semicolon.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Did you check the results". You can check the results for yourself. I am using console.log(), so you'll need to use the browser's console. Otherwise, fork the fiddle and change the console.log to alert. One other thing: I didn't want an infinite loop, so I replaced setInterval to setTimeout.

Comment: I think this is the limit for comments here and I'm actually at work and don't really have time to chat. The fiddle should show you the way.